# Wenzhixin bootstrap-table breaking Knockout.js bindings

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to integrate the [Bootstrap Table extension](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) into my application.  It works well generally but I am having problems with binding breaking on my knockout observables.

This code [available on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scotie/yu9q0jyp/) illustrates the issue.  The binding to the textbox is broken when bootstrapTable() is called for the table.  If you comment out the last line, everything works great.

**Javascript**

```
var order = {
  Id: 1,
  CustomerName: 'A Customer',
  Lines: [{
    ProductCode: 'Prod_1',
    Cost: 11.11,
    Qty: 1
  }, {
    ProductCode: 'Prod_2',
    Cost: 22.22,
    Qty: 2
  }, {
    ProductCode: 'Prod_3',
    Cost: 33.33,
    Qty: 3
  }, ]
};

var orderMapping = {
  'Lines': {
    create: function(options) {
      return new orderLineViewModel(options.data);
    }
  }
}

var orderLineViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
if (data != null) {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}
  self.LineValue = ko.computed(function() {
    return (self.Cost() * self.Qty()).toFixed(2);
  });
};

var orderViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, orderMapping, this);
};

var viewModel = new orderViewModel(order);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

//Removing the line below results in ko working fine
$('#OrderTable').bootstrapTable({});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="OrderTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Line Value</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Lines">
    <tr>
      <td><span data-bind="text: ProductCode"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: LineValue"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: Cost"></span></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Qty" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only issue I see is when you update the quantity it updates the line value of all items?

Can be resolved very simply (Added 2dp formatting):

```
var orderLineViewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;

   if (data != null) {
      ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
   }

   self.LineValue = ko.computed(function() {
      return (self.Cost() * self.Qty()).toFixed(2);
   });
};
```

[Update to Your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58yqpwcn/2/)

Comment: Thank you tyler_mitchell.  I incorrectly posted the wrong version of the fiddle!  I've updated the question but perhaps I should close the question and reopen?  I'm new to S/O so unsure best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is you need call bootstrapTable before applyBindings,
$("#selector")BoostrapTable({}) -> recreate your html and you lose knockout bindings.

```
var orderViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, orderMapping, this);
};

$('#OrderTable').bootstrapTable({});

var viewModel = new orderViewModel(order);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When start sorting it erases the bindings.